# OAuth token, limit use by API

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have an oauth server that issues tokens with client_credential grant type. I'm trying to figure out how to use scopes (maybe something different) to limit what the token has access to:
1) use GET for API1
2) use GET/POST for API2
3) no access at all to API3

I assume this has to be possible. Is scope the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few mechanisms:

- Audience can limit access tokens to use by specific APIs
- Scopes can limit the privileges a token has - maybe start with read / write scopes

OAuth mechanisms are not usually a good fit for more fine grained authorization checks - use API claims for that. Generally claims can come from multiple places, including:

- The access token
- Your product database